# using pocketsphinx_continuous with a .wav file

Tags: ffmpeg, cmusphinx, sox

I am attempting to write an application that will allow a user to speak a small set of commands from a remote system and have them executed on my server.  Using pocketsphinx to parse the spoken text.  When run locally with the microphone, pocketsphinx_continuous works perfectly no matter how I slur the words.  But when importing the audio file and using ffmpeg to downsample the audio to a single channel, 16 bit PCM  file, it will parse the first word without difficulty.  Then it will skip everything else and treat it as .  I am confident that the problem is in the file format and not in the pocketsphinx configuration.

Using command line 
`ffmpeg -y -i Sound\AddSheet.wav -ac 1 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16k AddTmp.wav`
in a batch file.

The bottom of the output I get is:

```
INFO: fsg_search.c(1407): Start node ADD.0:5:47
INFO: fsg_search.c(1407): Start node <sil>.0:2:49
INFO: fsg_search.c(1446): End node <sil>.126:128:305 (-486)
INFO: fsg_search.c(1662): lattice start node <s>.0 end node <sil>.126
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1352): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(<sil>:126:305) = -175371
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1390): Joint P(O,S) = -176076 P(S|O) = -705
000000000: ADD USER
```

Which is not the audio in the file.  The words spoken in the file are "ADD SPREADSHEET", which works perfectly from the same microphone without the intervening .wav file.

I have tried increasing the audio volume and decreasing the background noise using sox:

```
sox -v 3.0 Sound\%1 Sound\%1-loud.wav ffmpeg -i Sound\%1-loud.wav -vn -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:01 -y Sound\%1-noiseaud.wav 
sox Sound\%1-noiseaud.wav -n noiseprof Sound\%1-noise.prof 
sox Sound\%1 Sound\%1-clean.wav noisered sound\noise.prof 0.21 
ffmpeg -y -i Sound\%1-clean.wav -ac 1 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16k AddTmp.wav
```

with no noticeable effect on the final results.

If you look at the output you will notice that fsg_search.c has found ADD as the start node, then silence for the remainder.  Please help on this.

Comment: Share the grammar and the file itself. You can pack them to an archive, upload to a public file sharing resource and give here a link.